# My Json isn't parsing properly

Tags: php, json

simple script gets a json file, strips out extraneous headers, and tried to access a single key/value with no luck. anyone?

### CODE

```
$postURL = "http://case42.com/ogle/GetTarget.php?targetid=32feaf056b8c46e4a6f5500b6289cf59";
$json = file_get_contents($postURL);
echo "original response = <P>" . $json ."<HR>";
$strip = "target_record";
$mypos = strpos($json, $strip);
$json = substr($json,$mypos+15);
echo "My Trimmed json is: <P>" . $json."<HR>";
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
echo "<P>The print _ r of the trimmed json prints:<P> " . print_r ($json);
echo "<HR>";

echo "using \"\$obj->{'target_id'}\" to get name give me this: ".$obj->{'name'}."<HR>";
```

### The results are:

original response =

```
GET
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

Mon, 16 Dec 2013 10:36:23 GMT
/targets/32feaf056b8c46e4a6f5500b6289cf59{"target_record":{"target_id":"32feaf056b8c46e4a6f5500b6289cf59","name":"Francesca Grace","width":300.0,"active_flag":true,"tracking_rating":5,"reco_rating":""},"status":"success","result_code":"Success","transaction_id":"23029749e4984e2d92dbfb5ff44f8834"}
```

My Trimmed json is:

```
{"target_record":{"target_id":"32feaf056b8c46e4a6f5500b6289cf59","name":"Francesca Grace","width":300.0,"active_flag":true,"tracking_rating":5,"reco_rating":""},"status":"success","result_code":"Success","transaction_id":"b427cb1f89544b4c85332ca0ad174848"}
```

The `print_r` of the trimmed json prints:

1
using `"$obj->{'target_id'}"` to get name give me this:

Comment: [Because it is invalid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/). (the reason for this is that you forgot `{"target_record":` in your *trimmed* output).

Comment: Just fixed that - SAME result... see http://case42.com/ogle/testjson.php

Comment: [Again, cannot confirm..](http://codepad.org/nxpxu0hZ). Are you trying `echo print_r($array)`? If so, that's not how to use `print_r`. Read the [manual](http://www.php.net/print_r). "*When the return parameter is TRUE, this function will return a string. Otherwise, the return value is TRUE.*"

Comment: No, I was using print_r to see what was in the object - removing that line still has no affect on the ability to access $obj->{'name'}

Comment: Because when you use `,true`, again, as [per the manual](http://www.php.net/json_decode) ("*When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.*"), it returns an array. The way to access *objects* in PHP is `$obj->key`, but *arrays* are `$array['key']`.

Comment: OK -I switched my access to $obj['name'] - **same results, no value shown.**  Thanks for the tip on the "true" parameter, though.

Comment: That's because, [as the output of print_r gives you in my previous example](http://codepad.org/nxpxu0hZ) it isn't `$obj['name']`, but rather `$obj['target_record']['name']`.

Comment: THANK YOU!  I've been awake far too long, and just couldn't see this properly - GREAT help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$postURL = "http://case42.com/ogle/GetTarget.php?targetid=32feaf056b8c46e4a6f5500b6289cf59";
$json = file_get_contents($postURL);
echo "original response = <P>" . $json ."<HR>";
$strip = "target_record";
$mypos = strpos($json, $strip);
$json = substr($json,$mypos-2);
echo "My Trimmed json is: <P>" . $json."<HR>";
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
echo "<P>The print _ r of the trimmed json prints:<P> " . print_r ($json);
echo "<HR>";

echo "using \"\$obj->{'target_id'}\" to get name give me this: ".$obj['tagret_record']['name']."<HR>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: using "true" in the json_decode converts the object to an associative array.  Items inside are then accessed at $Array[$key][key].